# A question on functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

[image]

My attempt of this questions ,actually the ans only a but i am getting a,b,c how?please help

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to transcribe your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f'(k)
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(k+h)-f(k)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(k)+f(h)-f(k)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(h)g(h)}{h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left( \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} \right) \left( \lim_{h\to0} g(h) \right) \\
&=& 1 \times k \\
&=& k
\end{array}$$

Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} g(h)$ exists and is equal to $g(0)$ because $g$ is continuous.

---

(b) and (c) are wrong for a simple reason: $f'(k)$ is a constant and does not depend on $x$.